# Why does “Add Wireshark to the system path” fail to make man work?

Tags: macos, wireshark

I used `Wireshark 3.2.2 Intel 64` to install Wireshark on macOS 10.15.3. And I installed `ChmodBPF` and `Add Wireshark to the system path`.

`tshark` work in `Oh My Zsh` with `iTerm2`:

```
 $ tshark -h
TShark (Wireshark) 3.2.2 (v3.2.2-0-ga3efece3d640)
Dump and analyze network traffic.
See https://www.wireshark.org for more information.
```

But `man tshark` does not work:

```
$ man tshark
No manual entry for tshak
```

`Wireshark` has been put into `/etc/manpaths.d`:

```
$ cat /etc/manpaths.d/Wireshark
/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/Resources/share/man
```

But if I add `/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/Resources/share/man` to `MANPATH`, `man tshark` works:

```
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/man:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman:
$ export MANPATH="$MANPATH:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/Resources/share/man"
$ echo $MANPATH
/usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/man:/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnuman::/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/Resources/share/man
$ man tshark
SHARK(1)                             The Wireshark Network Analyzer                             TSHARK(1)



NAME
       tshark - Dump and analyze network traffic
```

I also added `/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Man` to `/etc/manpaths.d/TeX`:

```
$ cat /etc/manpaths.d/TeX
/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Man
```

`man pdflatex` works:

```
$ which pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
$ man pdflatex
PDFTEX(1)                                                      PDFTEX(1)



NAME
       pdftex - PDF output from TeX

SYNOPSIS
       pdftex [options] [&format] [file|\commands]

DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Apparently, what’s in `manpaths.d` will only be considered if _any_ `$MANPATH` is set in the first place (during `/etc/profile`, I guess).

Comment: Did you have MANPATH set initially?

Comment: Yes, I set MANPATH in .zshrc. I am using oh-my-zsh.